# How to get location information in background using fusedloaction api even when gps is turned off forcefully by the user?

Tags: java, android, gps

Hello am new for android development i need to get user location for every 15 minutes in background task for that i have use googleapiclient for getting location updates when gps is turned off how get the location updates using fused api client is there any way how the app like ola cabs use can anyone helpme out let me post my code what i tried so far:

```
public class Locationlistener implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener  {


    private Location mlocation; // location
    private double latitude; // latitude
    private double longitude; // longitude
    private GoogleApiClient mGAC;
    private Context mContext;
    public static final String TAG = "GPSresource";
    private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    public Locationlistener(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
        try {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGAC.connect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
        fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
        mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
       }


    public double getLatitude(){
        if(mlocation != null){
            latitude = mlocation.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (mlocation != null) {
            longitude = mlocation.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    public Location GetLocationBlocking() throws InterruptedException {



        //      String lat=String.valueOf(moCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        //    String longt=String.valueOf(moCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
//        Toast.makeText(oContext,"Lat"+lat+"long"+longt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return mlocation;

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (mGAC != null) {

            Location oLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGAC);
            mlocation = oLocation;
            getLatitude();
            getLongitude();
            if (oLocation != null){
              Log.d("lat",String.valueOf(mlocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.d("long",String.valueOf(mlocation.getLongitude()));
            }
            else{
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGAC, locationRequest, this);
        }   }}


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mlocation=location;
    }
}
```

how to make it work even when gps is turned off thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

> PRIORITY_LOW_POWER

instead of

> PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

The last one will try to use network location over GPS. I dont know what did you define in you Manifest.xml, but if you defined

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

I would change it for

> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: i have defined both i need like if gps available get gps location or network based location how to do it